# Get distance between two points in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have canvas drawing tab and want lineWidth to be based on distance between two last mousemove coordinate updates. I will make translation of distance to width myself, I just need to know how to get distance between those points (I already have coordinates of those pointes).

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You can do it with pythagoras theorem

If you have two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)
then you can calculate the difference in x and difference in y, lets call them a and b.

[image]

```
var a = x1 - x2;
var b = y1 - y2;

var c = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );

// c is the distance
```

Comment: you can shorten 
    var c = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );
to var c  = Math.hypot(a,b);

Comment: a^2 + b^2 = c^2 Hypotenus equation

Comment: Is it any difference if you go `x1 - x2, y1 - y2` or `x2 - x1, y2 - y1`?

Comment: @RamzanChasygov There is no difference in this case because each value is squared! So whether the order was like `7 - 5 = 2` or `5 - 7 = -2` won't matter.
`-2 * -2 = 4`
`2 * 2 = 4`

Answer (score 190):

Note that `Math.hypot` is part of the ES2015 standard. There's also a good polyfill on the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) for this feature.

So getting the distance becomes as easy as `Math.hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1)`.

Comment: I won't recommend using `Math.hypot()` to calculate the distance when performances matters. It is about 100 times slower.

Comment: Here is an explanation of why the Math.hypot is slower, basically because it is going to be more accurate. That may or may not matter to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764978/why-hypot-function-is-so-slow

Answer (score 36):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

If you have the coordinates, use the formula to calculate the distance:

```
var dist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x1-x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1-y2), 2) );
```

If your platform [supports the `**` operator](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-exponentiation_(**)_operator), you can instead use that:

```
const dist = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2);
```

Answer (score 16):

To find the distance between 2 points, you need to find the length of the hypotenuse in a right angle triangle with a width and height equal to the vertical and horizontal distance:

```js
Math.hypot(endX - startX, endY - startY)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick one-liner to find the distance between `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`

```
const distance = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
```

Here is a short runnable demo:

```js
const distance = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1); 

var x1 = 1
var y1 = 5

var x2 = 4
var y2 = 5

var d = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)

console.log(`The distance between (${x1}, ${y1}) and (${x2}, ${y2}) is ${d}`)
```

Answer (score 3):

i tend to use this calculation a lot in things i make, so i like to add it to the Math object:

```
Math.dist=function(x1,y1,x2,y2){ 
  if(!x2) x2=0; 
  if(!y2) y2=0;
  return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)); 
}
Math.dist(0,0, 3,4); //the output will be 5
Math.dist(1,1, 4,5); //the output will be 5
Math.dist(3,4); //the output will be 5
```

**Update:**

this approach is especially happy making when you end up in situations something akin to this (i often do):

```
varName.dist=Math.sqrt( ( (varName.paramX-varX)/2-cx )*( (varName.paramX-varX)/2-cx ) + ( (varName.paramY-varY)/2-cy )*( (varName.paramY-varY)/2-cy ) );
```

that horrid thing becomes the much more manageable:

```
varName.dist=Math.dist((varName.paramX-varX)/2, (varName.paramY-varY)/2, cx, cy);
```

Answer (score 3):

The distance between two coordinates x and y!
x1 and y1 is the first point/position, x2 and y2 is the second point/position!

```js
function diff (num1, num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) {
    return (num1 - num2);
  } else {
    return (num2 - num1);
  }
};

function dist (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var deltaX = diff(x1, x2);
  var deltaY = diff(y1, y2);
  var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2));
  return (dist);
};
```

Comment: You should use `Math.abs` instead of `diff`.

Comment: You don't need to use `diff` as squaring a number will always result in a positive number. If `x1 - y1` is negative, `(x1 - y1) ^ 2` is positive still.