# Javascript - how to calculate midpoint of linestring?

Tags: javascript, geojson

With given GeoJSON linestring:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            2.6806640625,
            46.437856895024204
          ],
          [
            4.7021484375,
            50.20503326494332
          ],
          [
            13.271484375,
            47.010225655683485
          ],
          [
            17.2265625,
            52.855864177853974
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to find exact middle point. I don't mean the middle element of a given array but calculating a midpoint which is exactly placed at the middle of line. So, if a line is 30km long in total then midpoint would be placed at 15km.

I tried searching npm for something like that but couldn't find. The only library which is close gives ability to place n points on line, and then I can get the middle one. But it's pretty bad in my case because precision is not that good.

Perfect option would be implementation of this http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html in JavaScript.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is a linestring? Why does it have four points? Shouldn't a line have only two points?

Comment: @fafl Linestring description can be found here: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring

Comment: I updated my answer, been working on it for a while now. finally got it! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here's a working CodePen](http://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/pezdbe)

the following code will return the point at a specific distance.

for this specific case the midpoint distance is total length / 2

call the main function like this, assuming our linestring array is stored in `points`

```
var totalLength = totalLen(points);
var midDistance = totalLength / 2;
var midPoint = getPointByDistance(points, midDistance)
```

##Javascript

```
myData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
           2.6806640625,
          46.437856895024204
        ],
        [
          4.7021484375,
          50.20503326494332
        ],
        [
          13.271484375,
          47.010225655683485
        ],
        [
          17.2265625,
          52.855864177853974
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
}
var points = myData.features[0].geometry.coordinates
var totalLength = totalLen(points);
var midDistance = totalLength / 2;
var midPoint = getPointByDistance(points, midDistance)
alert ("midPoint = " + midPoint[0] + ", " + midPoint[1])
// main function
function getPointByDistance(pnts, distance) {
  var cl = 0;
  var ol;
  var result;
  pnts.forEach(function(point, i, points) {
    ol = cl;
    cl += i ? lineLen([points[i-1], point]) : 0;
    if (distance <= cl && distance > ol){
      var dd = distance - ol;
      result = pntOnLine([points[i-1], point], dd);
    }
  });
  return result
};
// returns a point on a single line (two points) using distance // line=[[x0,y0],[x1,y1]]
function pntOnLine(line, distance) {
  t = distance / lineLen(line)
  xt = (1 - t) * line[0][0] + (t * line[1][0])
  yt = (1 - t) * line[0][1] + (t * line[1][1])
  return [xt, yt]
};
// returns the total length of a linestring (multiple points) // pnts=[[x0,y0],[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]
function totalLen(pnts) {
  var tl = 0;
  pnts.forEach(function(point, i, points) {
    tl += i ? lineLen([points[i - 1], point]) : 0;
  });
  return tl;
};
// returns the length of a line (two points) // line=[[x0,y0],[x1,y1]]
function lineLen(line) {
  var xd = line[0][0] - line[1][0];
  var yd = line[0][1] - line[1][1];
  return Math.sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);
};
```

##Explanation

**1. we find the total length of the linestring:**

- function `lineLen()` calculates the length of a single line.
- function `totalLen()` loops through the lines and calculates the total length.
  [image]

*source and credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916953/get-distance-between-two-points-in-canvas) (*Igor Šarčević*)

**2. the distance of midpoint is total length / 2:**

- now that we have the wanted distance we loop through lines and check distance of *this line-startpoint* and *this line-endpoint* and see if *midpoint distance* is between them.
- once we have the single line that we know our midpoint is on we calculate it's distance from this *line-startpoint* (total length - line-startpoint distance)
- now we use [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175896/finding-a-point-along-a-line-a-certain-distance-away-from-another-point) (function `pntOnLine()`) to find `xt`,`yt` (wanted midpoint)

[image]

*credits to *Sen Jacob*.

---

##Visualization
I included an HTML5 `canvas` to draw (visualize) the linestring and midpoint, you don't have to include them. but they're useful if you want to test the code and see the result live

```
// Just for visualizing on canvas (not needed)
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
drawLine(points);
//
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(midPoint[0], midPoint[1], 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
//
function drawLine(pnts) {
  pnts.forEach(function(point, i, points) {
    if (i === 0) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
    }
    if (i === points.length - 1) {
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this for simple lines or taking care of the curvature of a sphere?

Comment: In `getPointByDistance` function, the result of `totalLen` (the first line) is assigned to a var `tl` but `tl` is unused in the function body. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I can't remember why I did that, but you're right. it is unused.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you have a list of coordinates, that describe a line with waypoints on a sphere. Every coordinate has latitude and longitude.
This implementation goes through the lines until it reaches 50% of the distance:

```js
var coordinates = [
  [
    2.6806640625,
    46.437856895024204
  ],
  [
    4.7021484375,
    50.20503326494332
  ],
  [
    13.271484375,
    47.010225655683485
  ],
  [
    17.2265625,
    52.855864177853974
  ]
];

// From http://stackoverflow.com/a/18883823/5710637
function calcCrow(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) 
{
  var R = 6371; // km
  var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
  var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
  var lat1 = toRad(lat1);
  var lat2 = toRad(lat2);

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c;
  return d;
}

// Converts numeric degrees to radians
// From http://stackoverflow.com/a/18883823/5710637
function toRad(Value) 
{
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}

// Returns a point from a line
// Should use halversine but i'm too bad at math
function getPoint(factor, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
{
  while (lat1 < 0) {lat1 += 360}
  while (lat2 < lat1) {lat2 += 360}
  latPoint = lat1 + factor * (lat2 - lat1)
  latPoint = ((latPoint + 180) % 360) - 180
  otherLat = latPoint < 0 ? latPoint + 180 : latPoint - 180
  latPoint = Math.abs(latPoint) < Math.abs(otherLat) ? latPoint : otherLat
  lonPoint = lon1 + factor * (lon2 - lon1)
  return [latPoint, lonPoint]
}

function getHalfDistance(coordinates)
{
  // Calculate complete distance
  var totalDistance = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    totalDistance += calcCrow(coordinates[i-1][0], coordinates[i-1][1], coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1])
  }

  // Find the 50%
  var target = 0.5
  var currentDistance = 0
  for (var i = 1; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    var thisDistance = calcCrow(coordinates[i-1][0], coordinates[i-1][1], coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]);
    if (target * totalDistance < currentDistance + thisDistance) {
       var midDistance = target * totalDistance - currentDistance;
       var factor = midDistance / thisDistance;
       return getPoint(factor, coordinates[i-1][0], coordinates[i-1][1], coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]);
    }
    currentDistance += thisDistance
  }
}

console.log(getHalfDistance(coordinates))
```