# Calculate which of coords in object is closest to choosen coords

Tags: javascript, math

I have some objects in array with coordinates.

```
var players = [
{x:100, y:100, pid:1},
{x:-100, y:200, pid:2},
{x:600, y:1200, pid:3}
]
```

`var mousepos = {x:50, y:0}`

`var selected = null`

And I want to calculate which of these objects have closest coordinates to mousepos to select it pid
`selected = pid of closest coords to mousepos`

if anyone could give me easy done code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get distance between two points in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916953/get-distance-between-two-points-in-canvas)

Comment: Agreed, it looks like a simple Pythagore's theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example given by random from discord

```
    let closestPlayer = undefined;
    let closestDist = undefined;
    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      let player = players[i];
      let distance = Math.hypot(player.x - mousepos.x, player.y - mousepos.y);
      if (closestPlayer == undefined || distance <= closestDist) {
        closestPlayer = player;
        closestDist = distance;
      }
    }
      console.log(closestPlayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate here is the answer. Use the distance formula to calculate the distance between points. One with the smallest distance is the closest point.

Fomula :-  Sqrt((x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Value sometimes is NaN do you know why? also how can i select players.pid then?

Comment: @Zimek "Value is sometimes NaN" when? For what inputs?

Comment: @Zimek Well NaN means not a number so. What you can do is make sure all the numbers before testing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to calculate [Euclidean Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). If so then you can use [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) build in object. Once the distance is calculated then you can return the `index`. Using this index retrieve the he object from the players

```js
var players = [{
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    pid: 1
  },
  {
    x: -100,
    y: 200,
    pid: 2
  },
  {
    x: 600,
    y: 1200,
    pid: 3
  }
]
var mousepos = {
  x: 50,
  y: 0
}

function calculateEuclidean() {
  let selectedPid = 0;
  players.forEach(function(item, index) {
    let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((item.x - mousepos.x), 2) + Math.pow((item.y - mousepos.y), 2))
    if (index === 0) {
      selectedPid = index
    } else if (distance < selectedPid) {
      selectedPid = index;
    }
  })
  return players[selectedPid];
}


console.log(calculateEuclidean())
```

Comment: I want as return the pid of player that is closest not distance