# Shape borders of button created with divs

Tags: css, button, shapes, linear-gradients

I have to create a button with [the shape of a triangle in each side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugeKM.jpg).

My approach was to create a div that contains 4 more divs (one per corner) so I can shape the triangles by overlapping divs, using linear-gradient and white color for the background.

The problem is that I also need to edit a border for the shape created, and it is not possible because every div has its own border.

Any way to obtain borders just for the shape of the final button?

```css
.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 140px;
  position: relative;
  background: darkred;
}

.button:hover {
  background: black;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.text:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 8%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  right: 0;
}

.right {
  left: 0;
}

.down {
  bottom: 0;
}

.up {
  top: 0;
}

.left.up {
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, white 87%, white 87%, transparent 0%);
}

.left.down {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, white 87%, white 87%, transparent 0%);
}

.right.down {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 87%, white 87%, transparent 0%);
}

.right.up {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, white 87%, white 87%, transparent 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="button text">
  <span>Discover More</span>
  <div class="left up"></div>
  <div class="left down"></div>
  <div class="right up"></div>
  <div class="right down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Frankly SVG is your best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea with few code and CSS variables to easily adjust the shape:

```css
.box {
  --c:green; /* color */
  --a:30deg; /* angle */
  --b:3px;   /* border thickness */
  --w:20px;  /* width of of arrow */

  padding:30px calc(var(--w) + 20px);
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) top,
    linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) bottom;
  background-size:calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) var(--b);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before,
.box::after,
.box span::before,
.box span::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:50%;
  width:var(--w);
  border-right:var(--b) solid var(--c);
  border-bottom:var(--b) solid var(--c);
  transform-origin:0 calc(100% - var(--b)/2);
  transform:scaleY(var(--s,1)) skewY(calc(-1*var(--a)));
}
.box::after,
.box span::after{
  --s:-1;
}

.box span::before,
.box span::after {
  left:auto;
  right:0;
  border-right:0;
  border-left:var(--b) solid var(--c);
  transform-origin:100% calc(100% - var(--b)/2);
  transform:scaleY(var(--s,1)) skewY(var(--a));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span></span> some text here </div>
<div class="box" style="--c:red;--b:5px;--a:45deg"><span></span> some text here </div>
<div class="box" style="--c:blue;--b:2px;--a:25deg"><span></span> some text<br> here </div>
```

Comment: Your solution is amazing. Works perfectly well. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AbelMoreno thanks, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Comment: The only issue is the compatibility with Internet Explorer, but I guess it is impossible to adapt it to that browser.

Comment: @AbelMoreno for IE remove the CSS variables and put the value directly inside each property. You won't have flexibility but better support

Comment: I have tried that but still IE does not support certain features. I will have to create a SVG.

Comment: @AbelMoreno IE Support all of them, they simply need adjustement. fir example this : `linear-gradient(green 0 0)` need to be written `linear-gradient(green,green)` and you have to remove all the calc() too and replace them with the final value

Answer (score 0):

The final solution to attend full responsiveness was to create a SVG image as a Vue.js component, where size and shape (called "path" in a SVG) depend on the text inserted.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      width: 150,
      height: 8,
      triangle: 12
    };
  },
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    left: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    right: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rightTriangle() {
      const t = this.triangle;
      const h = this.height;

      return this.right
        ? `l 0 ${h} l ${t} ${t} l -${t} ${t} l 0 ${h}`
        : `l 0 ${h} l 0 ${t} l 0 ${t} l 0 ${h}`;
    },
    leftTriangle() {
      const t = this.triangle;
      const h = this.height;

      return this.left
        ? `l 0 -${h} l -${t} -${t} l ${t} -${t} l 0 -${h}`
        : `l 0 -${h} l 0 -${t} l 0 -${t} l 0 -${h}`;
    },
    svgPath() {
      return `m ${this.svgMargin.x} ${this.svgMargin.y} l ${this.width} 0 ${
        this.rightTriangle
      } l -${this.width} 0 ${this.leftTriangle}`;
    },
    svgHeight() {
      return this.height * 2 + this.triangle * 2 + 4;
    },
    svgWidth() {
      //https://stackoverflow.com/a/20916980
      //distance between [0,0] to [x, y]
      var triangleWidth = Math.sqrt(this.triangle * this.triangle);
      var numTriangles = 2;

      return this.width + triangleWidth * numTriangles + 2;
    },
    svgMargin() {
      return {
        x: this.triangle + 1,
        y: 2
      };
    }
  },
  watch: {
    text: {
      handler() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.updateButtonWidth();
        });
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateButtonWidth() {
      const iconSize = this.icon ? 40 : 0;

      this.width =
        document.querySelector(".atc-button-text").getBBox().width +
        40 +
        iconSize;
    },
    handleClickEvent() {
      this.$emit("click-event");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.atc-button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.atc-button-wrapper.push-left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.atc-button-wrapper.push-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.svg-content {
  position: relative;
}
.atc-button-content:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.atc-button-content path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ccba83;
}
.atc-button-content:hover path {
  fill: #ccba83;
  stroke: #ccba83;
}
.atc-button-content text {
  fill: #ccba83;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.atc-button-content:hover text {
  fill: white;
}

.atc-button-icon-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  top: -4px;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.atc-button-icon {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #ccba83;
}
.atc-button-icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.atc-button-content:hover ~ .atc-button-icon-wrapper .atc-button-icon {
  color: white;
}

.atc-button-icon-wrapper:hover ~ .atc-button .atc-button-content path {
  fill: #ccba83 !important;
  stroke: #ccba83 !important;
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="atc-button-wrapper">
    <div class="svg-content">
      <svg class="atc-button" :height="svgHeight" :width="svgWidth">
        <g @click="handleClickEvent()" class="atc-button-content">
          <path stroke="red" :d="svgPath"></path>
          <text
            class="atc-button-text"
            :x="icon ? '56%' : '50%'"
            y="52%"
            dominant-baseline="middle"
            text-anchor="middle"
          >{{text}}</text>
        </g>
      </svg>

      <div class="atc-button-icon-wrapper">
        <fa-icon :icon="icon" class="atc-button-icon"></fa-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```